# about android view design

Tags: android

I want to design android game program!

i use android DroidDraw program design UI view(Only 2.7" size)

absolutelayout.linearlayiut.tablelayout  have tried

However, the components designed address will change with different resolutions

how do design to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but you may try and peruse [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for a taste of "The Android Way".